# spring convert from deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Using SimpleJdbcCall.returningResultSet(ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper) is deprecated with Spring 3.0.5.  How would change my code to use a non-deprecated version of this method?

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private SimpleJdbcCall procGetReportExtras;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

    this.procGetReportExtras =
            new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("package")
                .withProcedureName("proc")
                 .returningResultSet("CURREPORTLIST",
                            ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Report.class));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` instead of `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper`

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withCatalogName("package")
            .withProcedureName("proc")
             .returningResultSet("CURREPORTLIST",
                        BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Report.class));
```

The call

```
 BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Report.class));
```

returns a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` instance which implements `RowMapper`. The non deprecated version of `returningResultSet` will be used.